# Xamarin Using references for OKHttpNetworkHandler & AFNetworkHandler

Tags: android, ios, xamarin, httpclient

I have been trying to implement ModernHttpClient as explained here: http://motzcod.es/post/78863496592/portable-class-libraries-httpclient-so-happy

the main problem is I cannot get it to recognise OkHttpNetworkHandler for Android or AFNetworkHandler for iOS - I don't know the using references for each. For Android I have System.Net.Http, ModernHttpClient and OKHttp. for iOS System.Net.Htp and ModernHttpClient. I have searched but cannot even find sample code that includes the usings

```
public class HttpClientHelper : IHttpClientHelper
{
    private HttpMessageHandler handler;
    public HttpMessageHandler MessageHandler
    {
        get { return handler ?? (handler = new OkHttpNetworkHandler()); }

    }
}  


public class HttpClientHelper : IHttpClientHelper
{
    private HttpMessageHandler handler;
    public HttpMessageHandler MessageHandler
    {
        get { return handler ?? (handler = new AFNetworkHandler()); }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Okay, seems you don't need any of that

Add the ModernHttpClient as a NuGet package to the PCL and then all you need to do is this

```
HttpClient client = new HttpClient(new NativeMessageHandler());
```

Works, and heaps faster than just HttpClient